# Which event involving Marie Curie is being referenced here?

Tags: biographical-details

In the second episode of "Super Science Friends" Tesla is telling of his fight with Edison that, in the comic, leads him to carry all his patents in the interior pockets of his jacket.

Freud [then](https://youtu.be/dmWvb1UXiZY?t=3m30s) comments

> "No chances that could ever backfire"

while looking at Marie Curie, that reacts quite angrily.

What is being referenced here?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I would guess that the reason is that your question, as posed, is not directly about the history of science.  Ironically, the answer is a biographical detail from the history of science.

Comment: @NickR I thought my question was specifically about a biographical detail, and the answer was not unexpected to me. The video I posted is full of biographical references, so I knew this was one of them, I was simply missing the fact it was being referenced. Do you think a rewording of the question would help?

Comment: Personally, I think the question if fine as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marie Curie died as a result of exposure to radiation.  This was, in part, the result of her carrying test tubes of radium in her pockets while doing her research.

Source [International League of Antiquarian Booksellers site](https://www.ilab.org/eng/documentation/608-marie_curie_-_a_woman_of_firsts.html) :

> One inadvertent and tragic discovery of hers was the effects of radium.  Much of her work was done in a shed, without the safety measures that are used today. She had remarked on the pretty blue-green light that the substances gave off in the dark, and kept test tubes in her pocket and desk drawer.  In 1934 she died of aplastic anemia from exposure to radiation.